# Firefox 50 update day... no update :(

Tags: updates, firefox

*Yesterday* was Firefox Update Day... unfortunately I don't see the update on 16.04. Is anyone else having this problem, and how do I fix my software sources to enable the update?

Answer (score 3):

It takes a little time for Canonical to process the Firefox updates and release them.  For example, Firefox 49 was released on [September 20 2016](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/49.0/releasenotes/) to release channel users.  It did not show up as an update on my systems until September 22 2016.

(extract from apt log)

```
Start-Date: 2016-09-22  09:34:27
Upgrade: firefox-locale-en:amd64 (48.0+build2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 49.0+build4-0ubuntu0.14.04.1), [....] firefox:amd64 (48.0+build2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 49.0+build4-0ubuntu0.14.04.1),[....
```

You do not need to do anything to your system unless a long time goes by and the update does not show up.  You can also check ubuntuupdates.org to (unofficially) see if the software has been released for Ubuntu.

[image]

** Update - it's in the repos as of 11/19/16

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

Open the command line `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T`and write

> sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list

Copy and paste at the end of the file the lines below

```
###### 3rd Party Binary Repos

#### Mozilla Daily Build Team PPA - http://edge.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ppa
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys  247510BE
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa/ubuntu xenial main

#### Mozilla Daily Build Team PPA (Source) - http://edge.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ppa
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys  247510BE
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
```

Once the text is copied press the keys  `Ctrl`+ `X`

Now write

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys  247510BE
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox
```